# How to catch multiple numbers occuring after certain word in text?

Tags: javascript, text

I want to catch numbers which are placed in text after word "NETTO-PRICE:" (there are few spaces in between too).

Text (eventually this text has got 2 lines/rows):

> PRODUCENT: AMD  MODEL-LINE: ATHLON  CORES: X2  MODEL: 7750  FREQ: 2.6 
>   CORES: 6  THREADS: 2  **NETTO-PRICE: 250.00**  QUANTITY: 7 PRODUCENT:
>   INTEL  MODEL-LINE:i7  CORES: X4  MODEL: 720QM  FREQ: 2.8  CORES: 4 
>   THREADS: 8  **NETTO-PRICE: 450.00**  QUANTITY: 5

I tried this: `string.match(/[0-9]/g);`but it catches all numbers in this text, when i only want those numbers after **NETTO-PRICE:**

This however doesn't work, cause it shows null: `string.match(/NETTO-PRICE:[0-9]/g);`

And if i am trying to concatenate this "arguments" in `match()` method, error comes up.

**[edit]**

I want to get only this numbers (as price), cause later i will be calculating brutto price and difference between netto (this numbers) and calculated brutto.

**[edit2]**
How to change this code below to make it work for variable with whole text, not just text in quotes? Something like `var s = string.split(' ');`And string contains whole text and furrther the code will be like:

```
var s = 'NETTO PRICE: 321.321'.split(' ');
if(s[s.indexOf('NETTO') + 1] === 'PRICE:')
    console.log(s[s.indexOf('NETTO') + 2])
else
    console.log('fake');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could use regular expression with non-capturing group (see [related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group)). Regular expression could look similar to this one: `/(?:NETTO-PRICE: )([0-9]+)/g`

Comment: It works, but i don't want to output "NETTO-PRICE:" with numbers, but only numbers which are behind this word.
Of course it can be other way than regex (match() method)

Comment: Since regexp contains `g` flag `String.prototype.match()` is not returning match objects. It should be used with `RegExp.prototype.exec()` method to get proper matches.

Comment: So how to solve it in other way than with regex? With split() or slice() maybe?

Comment: RegExp solution should work perfectly fine in this case. Just create RegExp and use its `exec()` method on string that contains numbers `var matches =  /(?:NETTO-PRICE: )([0-9]+)/g.exec(string);` . `matches` will be an array where all items except the first one will be matched numbers.

Comment: This time i got output : **NETTO-PRICE: 250,250**, so it cuts decimal ending of number and also second num should be 450.00 not 250.

Comment: Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stubb0rn/jhqc8yos/1/) that contains complete example of using `RegExp.exec()`

Comment: `var re = new RegExp(/(?:NETTO-PRICE:\s)([0-9\.]+)/g);
    var match;
    while(match = re.exec(string)) {
        console.log("Text...:"+match[1]);
    }`
This version of Yours code works, because i need to output this to console.**However** why are these numbers in match[1] kind of Array?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
var re = new RegExp(/(?:NETTO-PRICE:\s)([0-9\.]+)/g);
var match, i;
var nettoP = new Array();
while(match = re.exec(string)) {
      nettoP[i] = match[1];
      console.log("Text...: "+nettoP[i]);
      i++;
}
var nettoPrice = new Array();
var counter = 0;
for (i = (nettoP.length)-1; typeof nettoP[i] == 'string' ; i--)
{
    nettoPrice[counter] = nettoP[i];                        
    console.log("netto Price: "+nettoPrice[counter]);
    counter++;
}
nettoPrice.reverse();
console.log("Netto number: "+ nettoPrice);
```

**Thank you @Stubb0rn for help with Regex code.**